# react-bootstrap modal opens but won't close

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I originally had the code for my modal in the same component as the parent page and it worked fine, but now I've moved it out into it's own component I can no longer close the modal once it has been opened. I'm aware there are similar issues posted previously but they all seem to be using class components and I can't get the solutions to work for me.

I've stripped out irrelevant code for readability's sake

**Main component**

```
import { LoginModal } from '../partials/LoginModal';

export function SignUpButtonGroup() {
  const [showLogin, setShowLogin] = useState(false);
  const handleCloseLogin = () => setShowLogin(false);
  const handleShowLogin = () => setShowLogin(true);

  return (
    <Container>
      <LoginModal showLogin={showLogin} onHideLogin={handleCloseLogin}></LoginModal>
      ...
      <Button onClick={handleShowLogin} className="btn-sign-in btn btn-lg mx-auto" variant="primary">sign in
      </Button>
```

**Modal component**

```
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
export function LoginModal(props) {

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Modal show={props.showLogin} onHide={props.handleCloseLogin}>
      </Modal>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to the prop by its correct name `props.onHideLogin` in the Modal component.

It's only called `handleCloseLogin` in the Main component.

Comment: Omg I'm an idiot. Thank you so much, I love you. I'll accept the answer as soon as SO let's me (time limit for marking as answered)